# how to set up a loading page to preview while the website is loading in the backkground

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I have a website that take around a minute to fully load. Is there any way to show some loading animation or a picture while the website is loading in the background so when it finishes loading the picture will transition to the fully loaded website?  I have tried using `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1000; url = 'https://websiteurl.com'" />` by approximating the website load time but it usually varies significantly depending on the users internet connection.

Comment: Can you show what you have tried

Comment: just edited my question.

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-show-page-loading-div-until-the-page-has-finished-loading/ refer this

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that with a combo of `CSS` and `jQuery` as shown below.

```js
$(function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    $(".loader").fadeOut(500);
    $(".content").removeClass("loading");
  }, 2000);

});
```

```css
.content {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100% postion: relative;
  transition: all 2s;
}

.content.loading:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: white;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  transition: all 2s;
}

.loader {
  border: 16px solid #f3f3f3;
  /* Light grey */
  border-top: 16px solid #3498db;
  /* Blue */
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
  top: calc(50% - 60px);
  left: calc(50% - 60px);
  position: absolute;
}

@keyframes spin {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="content loading">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec varius tellus eros, ut pretium neque scelerisque ut. Etiam condimentum a quam at elementum. Nunc tempus tempus nunc sit amet aliquam. Pellentesque scelerisque turpis ut mi bibendum vestibulum.
  Morbi in purus vitae mauris efficitur mollis in a elit. Aenean maximus, turpis eget gravida semper, neque nunc sollicitudin orci, non tristique metus mi nec lectus. Integer congue eros eget est rhoncus, quis pharetra ex consectetur. Praesent sollicitudin
  pellentesque tellus, eget efficitur sapien aliquet ut. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia curae; Fusce venenatis dapibus velit et porttitor. Etiam quam tortor, iaculis non dignissim at, ultrices ut quam.
  Vivamus lacus diam, commodo at orci quis, tincidunt egestas ex. Nam finibus est tellus, in sodales sapien pulvinar sed. Integer lacus eros, bibendum nec condimentum ac, consequat nec est. Integer vitae urna nec tellus gravida sagittis vel vitae eros.
  Fusce viverra sollicitudin est, eget elementum tortor accumsan sed. Donec nec nunc vel nisl suscipit viverra. Praesent sit amet lorem at ex mattis malesuada at eu metus. In in felis in massa porttitor vulputate. Praesent id ultrices dui.</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="loader"></div>
```

**Note:** This is just one way to do it.